# "5 " in console is read as "ÿ5 "

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, decoding

In javascript, in the console of Google Chrome I write this code:

```
"﻿5 ".trimbegin()
```

trimbegin is a method that doesn't exist. What I get in the error in the console is this:
Uncaught TypeError: "ÿ5 ".trimbegin is not a function

I am not worried for the error, as I said the method is invalid. I want to know where does the ÿ come from? And how to get rid of it?

Comment: I see `feff` in Vim.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm